# LinkedIn Public Profile URL: get the public profile of LinkedIn in JSON format without using Login

Tags: linkedin-api, profile, public

Hello I am Working with Web Services with PHP.
I need the linkedin Public profile url in json format but i does not required login credentials, for that can we use linkedin Screen name of User!
Is this Possible to get the linkedin Public Profile withour authontication??????
Thanks and answers the Question Please

Answer (score 1):

not allowed. OAuth requires you to login first and you can then access only your details.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the [LinkedIn APIs Terms of Use](https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/linkedin-apis-terms-use), it is not allowed to use the API data without personal authentication. See section 3.A.g.